# Visual C# 2008 Express deployment

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment

is there any way I can add some files in the deployment process so they get copied in the installation? I need an xml file that has some data that the application needs, I tried every option in the build action for the file but nothing works, the application always crashes after the installation. Also, I'd like the program to be installed under the Program Files directory. The folder where VS Express installs it it's weird some C:\Users\Carlo\Temp\Applications\weirdnumbers9231FFC231\ directory, and I don't want that either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not trivial and wizardy to learn, WiX is the generally used free solution (and is a lot less messy and constrained than the built in vdproj stuff [that is in the Pro edition of VS]). There are a number of tutorials available on the web.